# comment_reply_link not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using custom code to call comments from database in wordpress(not through default wordpress comments functions) i.e I am using custom SQL queries to get comments from comments table and it is working fine. I need to add reply link under every link but there I need wordpress function and it should be this function

```
comment_reply_link()
```

I have the comment ID, now I need only to pass this ID in above function so I will get reply link of each comment. How can I pass the comment ID in this function?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check complete list of arguments of `comment_reply_link()` function from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_reply_link)

Also, check whether or not you have added `<?php comment_id_fields( $id ); ?>` in your comment form.